# cross domain ajax request in sencha touch 2.0

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, sencha-touch

I need soime data from other server using ajax request.
Is it posibel cross domain ajax request in sencha touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its possible, but i think you'd need to use jsonp as your data type